# Adding IEnumerable<T> items to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following:

```
 foreach (var item in selected)
 {
    var categories = _repo.GetAllDCategories(item);
    var result = from cat in categories
                 select
                     new
                     {
                        label = cat.Name,
                        value = cat.Id
                     };
}
```

The method `GetAllDCategories` returns a `IEnumerable<T>`

How to add `result` to new `IEnumerable` object that will contain all the items from `result` for all the selected items in the loop?

Comment: You can't add anything to an existing `IEnumerable`-> it is a read-only-collection!

Comment: you can use the extension method Concat to concatenate two ienumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think there is some confusion here,

```
var result = selected.SelectMany(item => 
    _repo.GetAllDCategories(item).Select(cat =>
        new
        {
            Label = cat.Name,
            Value = cat.Id
        });
```

seems to me what you want.

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to "squash" or "flatten" an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Its similar to having a function like this

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetSelectedCategories(
        IEnumerable<string> selected)
{
    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        foreach (var category in _repo.GetAllDCategories(item))
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(
                category.Name,
                category.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I call a genius way to read & answer a question. Perfect!

Answer (score 14):

Could you not use  [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)?

Something like

```
        IEnumerable<string> s1 = new List<string>
                                    {
                                        "tada"
                                    };
        IEnumerable<string> s2 = new List<string>
                                    {
                                        "Foo"
                                    };
        s1 = s1.Concat(s2);
```

Comment: +1 Concat is fine, also OP probably wants to concat multiple similar to King King SelectMany (+1 too) answer.

Comment: I think this is a misreading of the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = selected.Select(item=>_repo.GetAllDCategories(item))
                     .SelectMany(x=>x,(x,cat)=> select new {
                                                   label = cat.Name, 
                                                   value = cat.Id
                                                });
```

Comment: Gave an error `The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<TResult> System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult> (this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` I've put the type explicitly but didn't work!